# Xamarin Android - On relase issue

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin

I have created location tracking application. Today I have also added Geofencing feature. I is simple singleton class which raise event when geoposition is around given cooridnates.

When I manually raise event then it is working as expected. However when I set on release mode when coordinates are reached its stops an application. I have error log inside and everyting is written is: 
**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

I am using MVVMCross libary. My viewmodels attach to Geofencing service class witch callback. When user reach cooridnate then callback should be invoked. As I said in debug it is working.

Below code samples:

```
public class GeofenceService : IGeofenceService
    {
      //...
      public event EventHandler<GeofenceStatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;
      //..
    }


 public abstract class GeofenceViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
       protected IGeofenceService GeofenceService { get; }

       protected virtual void StartMonitoring(AddressModel address, MonitoringRadius radius)
        {
            MonitoredAddress = address;
            GeofenceService.StartMonitoring(new Location(address.Id, address.Latitude, address.Longitude), radius, GeofenceExpectation);
            GeofenceService.Subscribe(this, OnStatusChanged);
        }

 protected void OnStatusChanged(object sender, GeofenceStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           //...
        }
    }
```

Is there a way how I can get real exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in your **: Application** class init add Exeptions delegate

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e) => {
    //Save exeption to file (e.Exception.ToString ())
};
```

But my from my experience, I'll advise you to compare debug and release configurations (options) there may be some settings, that does not match and causing the crash.

Comment: Man this line of code saved alot of my time. Thanks alot !!